# AngularJS: Property on $scope is undefined at the child level

Tags: angularjs

I am creating an AngularJS application and I have a some controller for my view with a value on it called `$scope.restoreModalVisible` that I set to `false` upon initialization.  This value is going to be used in my DOM like

```
<div ng-if="restoreModalVisible" ng-controller="RestoreController">
    <!-- all my pop-up modal content -->
</div>
```

The problem is I have a bunch of directives on the page and one of them has to have access to this boolean value because it uses a button to toggle the value.  However, the value is not changing correctly.

I was under the impression that Angular "knows" to look up parent scopes if a value cannot be found at the immediate scope, so why isn't the property being modified at the child level?

In my directive's controller, I can see the value is I do something like `$scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.restoreModalVisible`

**My Directive's Controller:**

```
controller: function($scope, RestoreManager){
           $scope.restoreAccount = function(e, id){
               e.preventDefault();

               // Here we need to set the RestoreManager
               RestoreManager.set(id);
               $scope.restoreModalVisible = true;
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

how are you declaring the scope for the directive? If you use `scope: {}`, i.e. with an object, Angular will create an isolate scope which does not prototypically inherit from the parent scope (though the scope is still accessible through `$parent`)

Comment: Yeah I am using an isolated scope, but for some reason I still thought it was accessible at this point